# Google Directory API: Getting Not Authorized

Tags: .net, google-api, google-directory-api

Apparently - and *please* correct me if I am wrong - to use the Google API/Authorization correctly, you need to specify service account email ending in "@developer.gserviceaccount.com".

However, this account will not have access to the domain that I want to add/list/delete users to/from.  I assume this is the cause of my "Not Authorized" request.

How do you give this account permissions to the domain you want to affect change to?  Or - am I supposed to list a different account during authorization?  If so, how do I do that - since when I specify a domain account that *does* have permissions, I get "invalid_grant".

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

This is the code:

```
        String szDomainName = "testdomainname.com";
        String szServiceAccount = "google_generated_user@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"Google_Key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer ServiceAccountCredentialInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(szServiceAccount);
        ServiceAccountCredentialInitializer.FromCertificate(certificate);
        ServiceAccountCredentialInitializer.Scopes = new[] { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser };

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(ServiceAccountCredentialInitializer);

        // Create the service.
        BaseClientService.Initializer ServiceInitializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
        ServiceInitializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential;
        ServiceInitializer.ApplicationName = "List Users";
        var service = new DirectoryService(ServiceInitializer);

        var listReq = service.Users.List();
        listReq.Domain = szDomainName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to set the service account user you are going to act on behalf of. Even though you are using a service account you still need to set the service account user, the person in the domain you are acting on behalf of.

You can see the example here in the 'other' section.
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwtsample_java

Namely the line `.setServiceAccountUser("user@example.com")`.